# Aggregated range for multiple confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis

I am conducting a simulation involving 40 different stores in a specific area. Each store receives a varying number of customers in a given time period. I am calculating the expected final margin and the confidence intervals (CI) for each store over 100 repeated simulations.

My question is: once I have obtained the expected value and CI for the final margin of each store, is there a well-established method for determining the aggregated range of the confidence intervals for all stores? It is crucial for subsequent analysis to preserve the CIs of stores with the minimum/maximum final margins. Therefore, approaches that might diminish these characteristics, such as calculating CI from all expected values, are not preferable.

I'm attaching a figure showing what I prefer (basicly one range to represent all stores). Would this method make sense or any other suggestions?

[image: y axis as different stores, x axis as final margin. The bas are showing expected values and CIs from 100 runs.]

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate a CI for an "aggregated range" you will need to first be really clear on exactly what you mean by this ---i.e., what quantity are you seeking a CI for?  There are many possible statistics that could be formed for the aggregate of all stores, so you need to specify which one you are interested in, and this will then lead you to a method for getting an appropriate CI.

One commonly used quantity of interest (that would constitute an aggregation) is the *mean* number of customers over all stores, which would lead you to a CI that is very narrowly concentrated around the mean value averaged over the stores (or taking a weighted average of the stores).  This is obviously not what you are interested in here.  What you seem to be interested in here is the *range of the expected number of customers at each store* (i.e., the interval from the minimum expected number of customers at a store to the maximum expected number of customers at a store).  The CI for this would not necessarily be given by taking the endpoints of the two most extreme CIs, so you would need to look further into how to form this CI.

This is not a well-established method, mostly because this is not a very useful thing to know.  There is a huge loss of information in going from your initial plot showing all the individual CIs to going down to your final aggregated CI range (even assuming that this were corrected to use proper methods) and the latter does not really tell you much of interest.  In my view, there is little reason to try to get an "aggregation" of this kind rather than just presenting the plot showing the estimates/CIs for each individual store.  It might be useful to add an overall CI for the mean number of customers aggregated over all stores, but that would be all.

Comment: It looks a bit as though the OP is looking for a prediction interval about the summary statistic but it is not clear to me if that would meet their needs.

Comment: @Ben, thank you so much for the informative response. Please allow me to provide more details regarding my question: We are focused on calculating the 95% CI for the final margin across different stores, which is influenced not just by the number of customers but also by customer profiles and the varying store operating costs. So a CI based solely on the number of customers wouldn’t be very helpful. The primary motive behind exploring an ‘aggregated range’ arises from our subsequent analysis.

Comment: Post calculation of the margins for all stores, our objective is to evaluate the impact of various company policies (simplified as either injecting or extracting funds from stores) on these 41 stores to assess alterations in their final margins. While I totally agree that showing the CI for all 41 stores would be more of details, the challenge emerges when we consider the application of over 30 different policy tests, resulting in an overwhelming 41*30 CIs. Hence, we need an aggregated range as a simplified yet insightful comparison of policy impacts at a macro level.